# setting empty array in function argument

Tags: javascript

I was going through JS practise code (for interview) and I saw that the instructor have used/assigned empty array in function parameter

```
function walk(collection, result = []) {
  collection.forEach(item => {
    if(isTheItem(item)) result.push(item);
    else walk(item[0].children, result);
  });
  return result;
}
```

In general, is the above code and the following code equal

```
  function walk(collection) {
      const result = []
      collection.forEach(item => {
        if(isTheItem(item)) result.push(item);
        else walk(item[0].children, result);
      });
      return result;
    }
```

Even from the recursive point of view? and if not, can someone please explain me the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the above code and the following code equal

No, because in your second code, `walk` only accepts one argument, and every call of `walk` (whether recursive or not) will have a new `result`. Your second code will currently only output items from the top level in the collection.

To fix the second code, you would have to accept a second argument to pass along the `result`, something like:

```
function walk(collection, result) {
  if (!result) {
    result = [];
  }
  collection.forEach(item => {
    if(isTheItem(item)) result.push(item);
    else walk(item[0].children, result);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is basically a placeholder - if no paramater is supplied as a function argument, then an empty array is assigned by default.